# Long variable name fails in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Strings longer than 39 characters fail in dplyr, returning the error: "Error: index out of bounds".

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

### 40 characters does not work:

```
library(dplyr)

names(iris)[5]   <- "vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vvv40"

iris %>% dplyr::group_by(  vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vvv40 ) %>%

  dplyr::summarise( n() )
```

Gives me the error:
**Error: index out of bounds**

### 39 characters works:

```
names(iris)[5]   <- "vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vv39"

iris %>% dplyr::group_by(  vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vv39 ) %>%

  dplyr::summarise( n() )
```

Works fine. gives me this (desired) output

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

      vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vv39 n()
    1                                  setosa  50
    2                              versicolor  50
    3                               virginica  5
```

SessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.3.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.3.1      lazyeval_0.1.9 magrittr_1.0.1 parallel_3.1.1 Rcpp_0.11.3    tools_3.1.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be [**a known issue**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/705), to be fixed in `dplyr 0.3.1`. From the reply by @romainfrancois in the post:

"It happens here [...]

```
new_groups <- lazyeval::auto_name(new_groups)
```

because:

```
lazyeval::auto_name
function (x, max_width = 40)
{
    names(x) <- auto_names(x, max_width = max_width)
    x
}
<environment: namespace:lazyeval>
```

"

**Update**
In [`dplyr 0.4.0`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases/tag/v0.4.0) "`group_by()` supports variables with more than 39 characters thanks to a fix in `lazyeval`":

```
library(dplyr)
# Variable name with 40 characters
names(iris)[5] <- "vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vvv40"

iris %>% 
  group_by(vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vvv40) %>%
  summarise(n())
#   vvv_5vvv10vvv15vvv20vvv25vvv30vvv35vvv40 n()
# 1                                   setosa  50
# 2                               versicolor  50
# 3                                virginica  50
```