# dplyr group_by variable length limit

Tags: r, dplyr

I've had some problems with dplyr returning the error "index out of bounds".

It only seems to happen with long variable names. Obviously, this can be resolved by renaming the variable in question, but I wanted to place this here to help others resolve the same problem as the returned error is not informative.

```
> test <- data.frame(name = rep(c("orange", "pear", "apple", "bear"), 2) , 
+                    value = rnorm(8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> 
> group_by(test, name) %>% summarise(mean(value))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

    name mean(value)
1  apple -0.34881128
2   bear  1.01526013
3 orange -0.68778455
4   pear -0.06635953
> 
> test$reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongvarname <- test$name
> group_by(test, reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongvarname) %>% summarise(mean(value))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : index out of bounds
```

Comment: If it happens with the latest version from github then file a bug report here: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues It happens in C code so its not obvious what the underlying problem is. [have just checked out latest dplyr and it still fails]

Comment: See also [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927812/long-variable-name-fails-in-dplyr/26929493#26929493)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible work-around is to use `quote()` within `group_by()`.

```
> group_by(test, quote(reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongvarname)) %>% summarise(mean(value))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  quote(reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyl... mean(value)
1                                    apple -0.34881128
2                                     bear  1.01526013
3                                   orange -0.68778455
4                                     pear -0.06635953
```